# Compiler is out of heap space in pass 2

Tags: c++

For this algorithm that I'm building I sadly have a huge amount of variables that I have to input (about 60.000). Before when I was using about 30.000 the code would still compile, but now when I try to compile it tells me:

Error   LNK1257 code generation failed
Error   C1002   compiler is out of heap space in pass 2

Judging by what I read, the suggestion is to break the source code up into smaller pieces. So what I did was move half of the variables into a file called source.cpp and simply did #include "source.cpp", which didn't work. Then I tried it as source.h, which didn't work either.

I'm using Visual Studio, and sadly taking out the variables is not really an option. What could I do to be able to actually run the program?

Some edits to clarify: Program runs perfectly in debug mode, program also runs perfectly when I randomly take out half the variables, so it really must be a sort of overload of variables that I can't seem to prevent.

Comment: Try using 1) arrays, 2) loops, 3) functions, 4) separate translation units (= "files").

Comment: By separate translation units (files), do you mean simply including other .cpp files that have part of the variables in them? Arrays and loops are not really possible, they're all distinct variables..

Comment: Can you not store the variables in a map?

Comment: Surely the impact of `#include` is simply to (effectively) cut'n'paste the included text into the including text -- i.e. it's a pointless exercise in this case ?

Comment: You have 60,000 unique variables?  You can't combine any of them into an array(s)?

Comment: The potential benefit of splitting the variables into two .cpps is that you compile each separately - `cl /c half.cpp`, `cl main.cpp half.obj` (assuming `main()` is is `main.cpp`).  You might also find the compiler can handle them even in one file if if they're differently scoped somehow - e.g. in a namespace or three.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You're (most likely) correct, I have 0 experience using #include for my own files. 

Chiel, I'm not sure what you mean by that, any chance you could elaborate?

NathanOliver I know it's crazy, but sadly I can't. I tried doing that from the very start, but it wasn't possible. That'd have made things so much easier.

Comment: `#include` simply incorporates the included file into the source you're compiling, as if it was part of the main source file. This saves no compilation resources, whatsoever, and makes absolutely no difference. You have to actually split your large set of variables into two independent, separately-compiled, translation units.

Comment: Looking at separately compiled translation units now, to be honest with you I have no idea how to use them. If anyone could link me or tell me how I would go about separately compiling different translation units that'd be very much appreciated, because I'm not exactly sure where to start. Edit: Thanks for all these quick responses by the way, it keeps amazing me how helpful people are on here.

Comment: I'd like to see this algorithm that needs 60,000 unrelated variables.

Comment: An illustration of why you need so many variables should make it possible for people to help with advice. Don't show us 60,000 variables, just 6 of them!

Comment: Just curious - did you write that code by hand, or you somehow generated it?

Comment: The 60,000 variables aren't unrelated, they are very much related :) They're values of stock markets at certain days in the past. So for example opening_sp500_06_06_2016 would be opening value of S&P 500 at 6th of June this year. These variables are then used to perform calculations with "genes" from a genetic algorithm. 
@Leon, the code for the algorithm? I wrote it, with LOTS of help from people on stackoverflow. The values for the variables I got from several databases. Why do you ask?

Comment: Can you please show us a small piece of your code, that mentions/uses several  such variables? I have a very strong feelling that you can replace them with some standard data structure (array, map, etc).

Comment: I am pretty sure that you didn't write all that code by hand. If you did, then you are a hero. Still, I am more inclined to believe that this code was generated programmatically. What I cannot understand is the following - how someone, who can create a program for generating such code, cannot figure out how to do it in a more proper way?

Comment: @Leon Not sure what you exactly mean with by hand, I did literally type those formulas out.. The variables I created using excel with a simple macro, a bit hard to explain but it wasn't rocket science. I'm sure there could have been smarter ways to do that, but I (as you might have noticed haha) couldn't figure out what the smarter/more proper way would be.

Comment: Sorry for being a skeptic - you are indeed a hero! Typing all those formulas involving 60,000 variables (even if you used copy&paste) is an outstanding feat. It's a shame that your compiler refuses to compile the code with so much human energy invested in it. How much time did it take you? Are you sure that you didn't make any mistakes while typing all that code? My sincere recommendation to you is to take a programming course. Believe me - it will allow you to avoid doing a lot of work that can be automated.

Comment: @Leon Well, Excel really did help a lot. Creating this algorithm + inputting all the variables took about 2 weeks where I probably worked on it for about 8 hours a day. Though to be fair a lot of that time was spent actually learning how to program in C++.

As far as the code is concerned, I'm 100% sure it's correct. I tested it again 5 minutes ago with less variables and it works perfectly. It really just seems Visual Studio won't accept this many variables in one program and I'm not sure how to work around it :(

Comment: Just a small addition for those still reading.. For some odd reason it is now properly functioning when I run it in debug mode, but won't build to release mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114375/discussion-between-milan-and-leon).

Comment: Looking at your pastebin, this seems to be an ideal use case for a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). Why not create a single map for, say, `increase_in_trading_volume`, use a date object as the key, and store the specific `increase_in_trading_volume`'s value as the value? You could create a map for each variable grouping - `increase_in_trading_volume`, `close_to_open`, `open_to_close`, etc.